# Blink example compilation error

Tags: arduino-due, compilation-errors

I just installed the Arduino IDE on Mac and connected the programming port to my Arduino Due. I selected the corresponding board from Tools (though not sure which ATMEL programmer I should choose) I click upload and it gives

```
In file included from /Users/deepayanbhadra/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/sam/1.6.11/system/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam.h:198:0,
                 from /Users/deepayanbhadra/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/sam/1.6.11/system/libsam/chip.h:25,
                 from /Users/deepayanbhadra/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/sam/1.6.11/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:42,
                 from sketch/Blink.ino.cpp:1:
/Users/deepayanbhadra/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/sam/1.6.11/system/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam3.h:59:37: fatal error: sam3xa/include/sam3xa.h: No such file or directory
   #include "sam3xa/include/sam3xa.h" 

compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Due (Programming Port)
```

I'm pretty bumped off as this was my first example. When I connect the USB to the board, the ON is green, the L above and TX below the programming port is yellow. Is this okay?

Comment: is there more to that error message? maybe have to scroll up in that bottom window

Comment: @ChadG: You're right. I've added what it says further.

Comment: Try and pin down whether or not your problem is specific to the Due by compiling for another board, e.g. UNO.  You don't need to have the physical board in order to compile, only upload.  The debug is showing you are missing a library file.

Comment: @MichaelT: It still gives different kind of errors with other boards. I'm wondering what the choice of Tools->Programmer-> ? should be

Comment: I use default AVRISP mkII from the IDE for UNO.  I'm not aware whether that is different on mac.

Comment: @MichaelT: When I choose AVRISP mkII from the IDE for UNO, it just gives 'Problem Uploading to Board' (which's okay because the board isn't connected) I only have a Due. So it seems specific to Due, right? Also, is this okay - the ON is green, the L above and TX below the programming port is yellow?